# CheckBoxes in a DataGridView. Change Style.Backcolor of checked cells

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have 9 `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`s in my `DataGridView`.
I would like to have the background color of the checked cells changed to yellow and back to white when unchecked.

With my code, if a cell is checked, the whole row color is changed.
I have example image of what it should look like.

```
Private Sub dgCustomerNumber_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgCustomerNumber.CurrentCellChanged

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgCustomerNumber.Rows
        Dim checked As Boolean = CType(row.Cells("PrintImaLabelsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value, Boolean)
        If checked Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Else
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Formatting (presentation) matter, hence, you could use the [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CellFormatting);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) event, which is raised when a `DataGridView` cell needs to display its `Value`.

Since you want to change the `Style.BackColor` of the currently formatted cell, it's better to set the Cell [DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) insted of the Row's.

Verify that the current Cell meets the criteria (it's a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` and it's `Value` is not null). Filter by `e.ColumnIndex` or column name, if required, to narrow down the columns where this formatting is applied.

If this all checks out, set the `Style.BackColor` either to `Color.Yellow` if it's checked (`e.Value = True`) or back to the `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` original value.

```
Private Sub dgCustomerNumber_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgCustomerNumber.CellFormatting
    If e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf dgCustomerNumber.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).CellTemplate Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
        dgCustomerNumber(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.BackColor =
            If(CType(e.Value, Boolean),
                Color.Yellow,
                dgCustomerNumber.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**:
Define, at run-time, a custom Cell backcolor for the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns`.

After you have set the `DataGridView.DataSource`, parse the auto-generated `Columns` and set the `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` to a specific Color, when the parsed type is the desired one:

```
'Set the DataSource
DataGridView1.DataSource = [MyDataSource]

For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    If TypeOf col Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Then
        col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Magenta
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I used the code above now if the checkbox = false how would I make the whole checkbox column magenta. until I check it to make it yellow.

Comment: columns are auto-generated by using a DataSource columns names

Comment: Jimi Thanks for the help !